Can I dispute ATM fees?
I was going through my statement the other day and noticed that the ATM had been taking $3 for a balance check. Can I do something to get these charges reversed?

We need more information to be able to help. Did they take $6 or $1,100 in these fees? What exactly is the fee for (should have a description in your statement)? What's the "sneaky way" you describe? Are the ATMs in question in the same network as your bank (or does your bank provide reimbursements for out-of-network ATM fees)?

It sounds like your account may be compromised and someone's doing balance checks to see how much money is available. Contact the bank, dispute the charges you don't recognize, and have them close that account and open another one.

Yes- contact your bank. You should clarify whether you actually did the balance checks on all the days you were charged. If you didn't, your debit card may be compromised (perhaps copied using a skimmer somewhere). If all of the charges are legit checks that you did, still go talk to your bank. There's a chance of getting many of those balance inquiry fees reversed in either case. (And stop checking balance at an ATM from now on...)

It seems a little silly to use the ATM for balance check.  Why not use your mobile app/phone?  That seems more secure and convenient.

When you use an ATM there are two ways you can be charged:

by your bank
by the owner of the machine.

Sometimes if you use a machine that is in a network your bank belongs to there will not be any charges by the machine owner. In some cases your bank will reimburse you for a small number of out if network uses per month.
To see which ATM network your card works with check the back of the card, or the bank website.
To know how they handle out of network fees check your bank website.
The website will also list off the ATM related fees and limits.
When I first got a ATM card decades ago it was normal to be charged $0.50 to check your balance. You were trapped into doing so because you couldn't use an app on a smart phone (because we didn't even have a cell phone), there was no webpage to log into, there wasn't even a touch tone phone interface. You either visited the bank in person, or waited for the monthly statement in the mail.
Today if you use the web interface, or the smartphone app, there should not be a need to use the check balance feature of the ATM. That can in your situation avoid a large amount of your fees.
Other ways to avoid most fees: use a debit card at the register to pay for things; use a credit card.
Both of these options have benefits and risks. If you are always flirting with going negative on your account a debit card doesn't solve that problem. If using a credit card will cause you to overspend, then moving from cash to plastic is risky.

Every ATM I've seen recently puts up a warning about transaction fees. $3 is fairly standard. You can reduce the bite by making a larger withdrawal so that is a smaller percentage if the transaction.
Some banks will cover the fees for some ATM networks. It's up to you to understand which your bank will and won't cover, how often. If you don't like the answer, you are free to open an account at a bank which does cover the ATMs you are interested in, or use different ATMs.
Read the literature your bank gave you when you got the card, or if you've lost it contact them and ask for a copy. That is what you agreed to in accepting and using the card.

Also, using cashback at stores may be an efficient way to avoid ATM fees.
